# Form Submit on Custom Admin Page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I wrote a products plugin that has a custom database table for storage and a single page for management. From that screen, admins will be able to insert new entries and delete existing ones.

With that in mind, both the create and delete buttons will post to the same page, where I will process them separately and handle the DB interactions. My question is, since it isn't an actual standalone page but rather `wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-test-plugin` how can I implement POST to Self?

[image]

```
<table class="apl_product_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Tag</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php' ); ?>">
                <td><input type="text" name="product_tag" placeholder="Shortcode ID" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_name" placeholder="Link Display Text" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_id" placeholder="Amazon Product ID" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_price" placeholder="Default Product Price" required></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Create"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: remove the action property, and the form will submit on itself

Comment: Ah that is so much easier than I realized, thank you! Do you want to make it an answer? The only other post I could find about it was considerably more complex so it may help others.

Comment: Yeah, i did ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want that a HTML-Form submit on itself, just remove the action attribute.